# How to Jump back to the loop increment stage inside a stored procedure if a condition is satisfied inside the loop?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a stored procedure as shown below which has a loop running inside it. If the condition mentioned below is satisfied I need to go back to the loop and start from the Loop stage. How can I achieve this?

```
..... some steps.........
while (@iv<= @rcnt)
Begin
CREATE TABLE #MathLogicTable 
(
IDNUM INTEGER IDENTITY(1,1),
ATTRIBUTENAME VARCHAR(256),
INPUTVALUES DECIMAL(15,3)
)

INSERT INTO #MathLogicTable
      SELECT  statements..................

if (not exists (select 1 from #MathLogicTable))
BEGIN
set @iv=@iv+1 (I need this step to go back to the start of the loop...if the condition satisfies)
END
------------------------------------------------------------
select............
update........
N Steps.........
-------------------------------------------------------------
End
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `continue` keyword:

```
if (not exists (select 1 from #MathLogicTable))
begin
    set @iv=@iv+1 
    continue
end
```